# working with excel files in uwp

Tags: vb.net, uwp

my question is - I can't read data from excel file. I'm using spreadsheetgear library. I'm writing for uwp platfom (I need to show user data from excel file). may someone help?
(gv1 = gridview). or I should use other library? May be anyone already worked with spreadsheetgear and can help.

```
Public Async Function open_excel() As Task
        Dim Values As String()
        Dim filepicker As New FileOpenPicker With {.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List, .SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Downloads}
        filepicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".xls")
        filepicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".xlsx")
        Dim storefile As StorageFile = Await filepicker.PickSingleFileAsync
        Dim workbook As IWorkbook = Factory.GetWorkbook(storefile.Path)
        Dim worksheet As IWorksheet = workbook.Worksheets(0)
        gv1.ItemsSource = worksheet.Cells
```

Comment: Please provide more details on what exactly doesn't work. Do you get an error, does the app crash, data is lost, something else? According to their website, spreadsheetgear supports UWP.

Comment: i have a group shedule in excel file, i need to show this info to user and sort by group if he wants, show shedule only for his group for example

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT i try to bind data from excel file to datatable or datagrid, but i cant find a solution for uwp on their site

Answer (score 0):

From [`spreadsheetgear`](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/nuget/spreadsheetgear/tutorials/mvc-web-app-excel-reporting-from-template/visual-studio-for-windows/) document, if you want to open Excel from a file you need to create `workbookSet` then invoke `OpenFromStream` method. I have tested, it works in my side.

```
StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
 if (file != null)
 {
     using (var steam = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
     {
         var workbookSet = Factory.GetWorkbookSet(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture);
         var workbook = workbookSet.Workbooks.OpenFromStream(steam.AsStream());
         var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
         var Used = worksheet.UsedRange;
         var items = Used.Value;
     }
 }
 else
 {
     return;
 }
```

Comment: thank u so much. it works. may be u also know a way how to show data to user? i wanted to use datagridview, but uwp dosent have it

Comment: There is `Cells` property in `worksheet`. And Cells is a rang type value. You could get the cell content with traversing the range.

Comment: zhu i tried like this: grid.itemsource=worksheet.usedrange.cells, but it gives nothing

Comment: The type of Cells is a range, you could not use it as list.

Comment: And how i should bind it? Documents of spreadseetgear and other libarys gives examples, which not working in uwp, only in winforms

Comment: I even tride to bind data to matrix massiv and then bind to grid, the same result

Answer (score 0):

I have a question, I use the code to open the excel, and if I want to save it, what is it the code?.

I use the code of open the excel. If you dont want open a windows dialog, and you prefer to give de path directly, you can use the following code:

```
var folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(@"C:\Excel_Modelo");
var file = await folder.GetFileAsync("Modelo.xlsx");
if (file != null)
{
   var workbookSet = Factory.GetWorkbookSet(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture);
   IWorkbook workbook = workbookSet.Workbooks.OpenFromStream(steam.AsStream());
   var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
   var Used = worksheet.UsedRange;
   var items = Used.Value;
}
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33134198)